# Multiple Typescript <Select> onChange handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

first let me say that I'm not a TS developer. So if I make a dumb question, let me know.
I'm trying to use multiple select, basically I need multiple dropdown menus.
Started with the simple [select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) from material-ui and I tried to develop forward.

I make it work with a single select, my problem is with that I don't understand how to add a new select using the `onChange` event

```
type OnChangeValue = {
  locationNaming: unknown;
};

interface ServerNamingDropdownProps {
  onChange(value: OnChangeValue): void;
  error?: boolean | undefined;
  initialValue?: string | undefined;
}

export const ServerNamingDropdown: React.FC<ServerNamingDropdownProps> = ({
  onChange,
  error,
  initialValue = undefined,
}) => {

  const [locationNamingSelected, setLocationNaming] = useState(
    initialValue ? initialValue : '',
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Location</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={locationNamingSelected || ''}
          label="Location"
          error={error}
          labelWidth={140}
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          onChange={e => {
            onChange({
              locationNaming: e.target.value,
            });
            setLocationNaming(e.target.value as string);
          }}        >
          {location.map(item => (
            <MenuItem value={item.abbreviation} key={item.key}>
              {item.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have to add a new dropdown for Department.
I understand that should add to `OnChangeValue` the `departmentNaming`.
But I don't understand how to manage the `onChange`.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look into [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

React will re-run your render when you change your state, i.e. when you call `setLocationNaming`. The output of the render function should be different at that point. As @mstephen19 said, what your function returns can be conditional on the props *or state*. Here's a very simple (untested) sketch:

```
const MyConditionalRender = () => {
  const [showMoreContent, setShowMoreContent] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowMoreContent(true)}>Show</button>
      {showMoreContent && (
        <p>More Content, like an extra dropdown for the department.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Do read the [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) docs that mstephen19 linked.